# Meteor Template 'Click Event' not fired after deployment on Meteor server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor, facebook-login

I am trying to login with Facebook on my Meteor App. And I have the following HTML button...

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-fb-login facebook-login"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Login With Facebook</a>
```

...to call the following login function in the JS file ...

```
Template.loginForm.events({
    'click .facebook-login': function(event) {
        console.log("clicked");
        var permissions = ['email', 'user_likes'];
        Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
            requestPermissions : permissions
            }, function(err){
                if (err) 
                    throw new Meteor.Error("Facebook login failed");

                if(Meteor.user().firstLogin) {
                    Router.go('/fbRegister');
                }
        });
    }
});
```

The whole thing works fine on Localhost but after I deploy the App on the Meteor server, the Facebook Login button doesn't do anything. There is no error and it doesn't even reach the console.log part. The 'Click' event just doesn't fire.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do `$('.facebook-login')` from your browser console in production just to be sure the DOM element is actually there. If it is then do `$('.facebook-login').click()` to see if that triggers the event.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Thanks for that. `$('.facebook-login') returned the HTML element but `$('.facebook-login').click()` threw this error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'newwindow.focus'). But I did get the 'clicked' print from the console.log.

Comment: That tells you the element is in the DOM and clickable. Could there be an event tied to a containing object that's grabbing the click and not passing it through?